# Backtracking ,recursividad

Tags: python

Alguien me explica como funciona este algoritmo ,sobre todo la parte else.

```
def bitStrings(n):
if n==0: 
   return []
if n == 1 :
    return ["0","1"]  
else:
    return [digit + bitstring for digit in bitStrings(1) for bitstring in bitStrings(n-1)]

#Using
if __name__ == '__main__':
print(bitStrings(2))
```

Resultado : ['00', '01', '10', '11']

Comment: No hay backtracking, solo recursividad. Backtracking es cuando ves que no vas a lograr llegar a la solución, y desechas el trabajo hecho para intentar con otra alternativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código produce una lista con todos los valores en binario desde 0 en adelante que tengan n bits. Por ejemplo, con

```
print(bitStrings(4))
```

produce

```
['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']
```

Si `n` es la cantidad de bit que queremos en cada valor de la lista, el código hace lo siguiente:

- Si n == 0, devuelve una lista vacia (valores con cero bits).
- Si n == 1, devuelve una lista ["0", "1"], que son los valores que se pueden escribir con un bit.
- Para n > 1 se usa

  [digit + bitstring for digit in bitStrings(1) for bitstring in bitStrings(n-1)]

Vamos a reescribir esto usando ciclos `for` anidados, una forma más trabajosa de expresar la comprensión de listas:

```
resultado = []
for digit in bitStrings(1):  # Equivale a for digit in "01":
    for bitstring in bitStrings(n-1):
        resultado.append(digit + bitstring)
return resultado
```

Para cualquier número, el primer `for` es simplemente:

```
for digit in "01":
```

El segundo `for` calcula recursivamente todos los valores binarios con `n - 1` digitos, que se concatenan con `digit` para producir valores con `n` digitos.

El código se puede simplificar aún más, reduciendo los `return` dispersos a un solo `return` al final de la función

```
def bitStrings(n):
    resultado = []
    if n:
        if n == 1 :
            resultado = ["0","1"]
        else:
            #return [digit + bitstring for digit in bitStrings(1) for bitstring in bitStrings(n-1)]
            for digit in bitStrings(1):
                for bitstring in bitStrings(n-1):
                    resultado.append(digit + bitstring)

    return resultado
```

#### Demo

```
resultado = bitStrings(4)
print(resultado)
```

produce:

```
['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!